# Is there some specific term or use for a line that is tangent to a graph at two or more critical points?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, tangent-line

We started learning about critical points on a graph in my calculus class, and it got me wondering about tangents that touch multiple critical points on this graph.  For example, the equation $y = sinx$ has an infinite number of critical points with a period of $\pi$, and infinite local maxima with a period of $2\pi$. Any tangent at a point that is a multiple of $2\pi$ will be tangent to every other point that is a multiple of $2\pi$.
[image]

Is there some specific term for tangents with this property?  Is there a special use for them?

Answer (score 1):

Up until now I don't think I've heard any special "names" for lines of this property.

We can use this property to make observations but I've never heard a name given to the actual line. have a look at Rolle's Theorem it might provide some additional insight into tangents and functions.